# The syntax of the command is incorrect TYPE command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a script that fails. I have isolated the problem to a simple TYPE command. Here is the code

```
IF NOT [%1]==[] ECHO Appending this log to %1
IF NOT [%1]==[] TYPE C:\test.log >> %1
```

As you can see, all I want to do is copy the log file to a specified location IF it is specified. The script should also run if there is no extra log file specified.

I can't figure it out because it looks correct and I have tried different things.The script runs fine if a parameter is passed in.

EDIT: I tried ECHOing that line and it appears like IF NOT [] == [] TYPE C:\test.log 1>>

Comment: +1 for using ECHO to help debug - that was crucial information needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script fails when %1 is empty because the entire IF statement must have valid syntax, even when the IF evaluates to false such that the body would not get executed.

You can solve the problem by redirecting to `"%~1"` instead of `%1`. The `~` is needed to strip any enclosing quotes that may already be present in the value. Redirecting to `""` is valid syntax. It would fail with a run time error, but not a syntax error. But it is not going to get executed if %1 is empty, so it doesn't matter.

I would use `"%~1"` in the IF condition as well instead of `[%1]`: It is a bit more robust.

I would also restructure the code to use a single IF, but that is more a matter of style.

```
if not "%~1"=="" (
  echo Appending this log to %1
  type c:\test.log >>"%~1"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great! I wonder why I didn't come across this in any of the tutorials I watched(I am just getting started with scripting)